# Tinymce, php not store data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, tinymce

I would use mysql to store the path of news saved with  tinymce,
but from the code post news save in folder and not insert into DB,
the strange thing is i don't get any errors from mysql.
here is my code, thanks and sorry form my bad english :D

```
<?php
/*

Configuration file
for write_post.php


*/
include ('config_db.php');
$query = "INSERT into news (path,count) values ('$qry', '1')";
$qry = NULL;
   $cat= $_POST['cat'] . "/";
   $newsTitel   = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : 'Untitled';
   $submitDate  = date('Y-m-d g:i:s A');
   $newsContent = isset($_POST['newstext']) ? $_POST['newstext'] : 'No content';
   $qry = $cat.$_POST['title'].".txt";

   //$filename = date('YmdHis');
   $filename = $newsTitel;
   $f = fopen($cat . $filename.".txt","w+");    
   fwrite($f,$newsTitel."\n");
   fwrite($f,$submitDate."\n");
   fwrite($f,$newsContent."\n");
   fclose($f);
   //$post = $cat . $filename . ".txt";
   if($mysqli->query($query)){
       echo "<br/>";
       echo "News inserita con successo!";
   }else{
       echo "<br/>";
       echo "Errore\n" . $mysqli->error;
   }
   echo "<br/>";
   // Try to echo $variable to check if is correct, and is ok but don't go into db 
   echo $qry;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are preparing the variable $query before preparing $qry. So try the following:

However, please note that you are neither using sprintf() with mysql_real_escape_string() not using mysqli variable replacement which are strongly recommended to avert database injection.

```
<?php
/*

Configuration file
for write_post.php


*/
include ('config_db.php');
$qry = NULL;
   $cat= $_POST['cat'] . "/";
   $newsTitel   = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : 'Untitled';
   $submitDate  = date('Y-m-d g:i:s A');
   $newsContent = isset($_POST['newstext']) ? $_POST['newstext'] : 'No content';
   $qry = $cat.$_POST['title'].".txt";

   //$filename = date('YmdHis');
   $filename = $newsTitel;
   $f = fopen($cat . $filename.".txt","w+");    
   fwrite($f,$newsTitel."\n");
   fwrite($f,$submitDate."\n");
   fwrite($f,$newsContent."\n");
   fclose($f);
   //$post = $cat . $filename . ".txt";

   // preparing query here
   $query = "INSERT into news (path,count) values ('$qry', '1')";

   if($mysqli->query($query)){
       echo "<br/>";
       echo "News inserita con successo!";
   }else{
       echo "<br/>";
       echo "Errore\n" . $mysqli->error;
   }
   echo "<br/>";
   // Try to echo $variable to check if is correct, and is ok but don't go into db 
   echo $qry;
?>
```

Comment: In that case kindly mark it also as useful! Thanks for the feedback!